# Installing a danish dvorak keyboard in fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, dvorak

I am using us-dvorak on my Fedora installation, but I would like to use a dvorak which also contains danish letters.

I do have the file /usr/lib/kbd/keymaps/xkb/dk-dvorak.map.gz but I don't know how to install it. I can do a setxkbmap dk and setxkbmap dvorak to change between danish and dvorak layout, but setxkbmap da-dvorak just gives me Error loading new keyboard description

I am using Kde, as my gui in case it matters.

I found the Solution:
It turns out that the keyboard selector in kde don't allow you to modify all details of an already added keyboard. So the solution is to add a new keyboard which can then be configured with the right language/layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104217/in-fedora-how-do-i-select-a-proper-norwegian-keyboard-layout

same issue as you, just as we norwegians would say, "dra meg nå baklengs inni fuglekassa"

Comment: Thanks. That link gave me a hint to really solve the problem. (Se my updated answer)

Comment: on ubuntu there is dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration, pretty sure fedora also has something simular